# PowerDI-123 socket pin assignment

Tags: diodes, pins, socket

Does anybody know which pin is cathode at **PowerDI-123** socket? *Diodes Inc.* datasheets are rather confusing and I have no real diode in hands to measure it. (I suppose larger pad is cathode because there is mark and suggested pad layout is reversed.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stripe on the right is indicating the *cathode*. On the very first page of the datasheet, it is stating:

> Polarity Indicator: Cathode Band

Comment: You are hopefully right. I found http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ap02001.pdf document where recommended pad layout is not confusingly reversed.